# flattening an iterable by removing one element at a time

Tags: python, loops, iterable

I have a list of tuples such as:

```
bins = [(0, 1500), (0, 1500), (2000, 40000)]
```

I'd like to flatten it out in a loop, but without one of the elements in every loop.

The expected result should be:

```
[0, 1500, 2000, 40000]  # first loop, first element is not there
[0, 1500, 2000, 40000]  # second loop, second element is not there
[0, 1500, 0, 1500]  # third loop, last element is not there
```

To flatten it out, I could use:

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain.from_iterable(my_iterable))
```

But I need to find how to get this `my_iterable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just use list slicing.

```
from itertools import chain

bins = [(0, 1500), (0, 1500), (2000, 40000)]
for i in range(len(bins)):
    my_iterable = bins[:i] + bins[i+1:]
    print(list(chain.from_iterable(my_iterable)))
```

Comment: Or you could use `for i in range(len(bins)):` to loop over indices if you are not using the values.

Comment: @alani yeah, I thought I was gonna need it at first but then forgot to change it in the end.

Comment: Anyway, in my view, your solution is the simple and obvious one. `combinations` (see other answers) feels unnecessary here.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I've understood your question right, but you can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```py
from itertools import combinations, chain

bins = [(0, 1500), (0, 1500), (2000, 40000)]

for c in combinations(bins, len(bins) - 1):
    print(list(chain.from_iterable(c)))
```

Prints:

```py
[0, 1500, 0, 1500]
[0, 1500, 2000, 40000]
[0, 1500, 2000, 40000]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `itertools.combinations`, but its culling order is opposite to what you want, so you have to reverse it twice:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, combinations
>>> for tpl in combinations(reversed(lst), len(lst) - 1):
...     print(list(chain.from_iterable(reversed(tpl))))
...
[0, 1500, 2000, 40000]
[0, 1500, 2000, 40000]
[0, 1500, 0, 1500]
```